# Velocity and acceleration of sliding blocks on a conveyer belt with friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

If we have a large conveyer belt sliding East with velocity, v, and shove a block moving South at velocity, v, it would be slipping initially. In the reference frame moving along with the sliding conveyer belt, the block has velocity $v\sqrt2$ or 2 velocity components: $ v$ in the South direction and $ v$ in the West direction. My question is, why can't we separate the two directions and apply the kinematic equation: $v_f = v_i + at$ for each direction with $ a = -g\mu$ to find the time it would take for the block to stop slipping? Applying the equation in the direction of the total velocity would certainly give a different time since $ v\sqrt2 > v$.

Is this because of the friction force having different components in each direction? What would that look like?

Comment: pleas ad the two different calculations you speak of, since in the end the block should move in east direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flaw in your analysis is that you have not used the fact that the frictional force has a constant magnitude $\mu mg$ and acts in a direction opposite to the direction of the velocity of the particle relative to the conveyor belt.

In this example the conveyor belt is an inertial frame so let's sit on it.
What do we see sitting on the conveyor belt at the beginning just as the block is projected South as seen by an observe on the ground?

Sitting on the conveyor belt we observe the block having a component of velocity $v$ to the South and a component of velocity $v$ to the West.
Thus at the very start the velocity of the block relative to the conveyor belt is $\sqrt 2\, v$ in the direction South-West.

Thus the frictional force acting on the block is $\mu mg$ (constant) in the direction North-East.
Note that in your description you had two components of the frictional force each with magnitude $\mu mg$ and thus a net frictional force of $\sqrt2\,\mu mg$.

You should now be able to answer your own question because you know the initial velocity of the block (relative to the conveyor belt) and you know the magnitude and direction of the frictional force acting on the block in the conveyor belt frame of reference.

Comment: -1 Why? It would be nice for me not to make the mistake I have made, whatever it is.

Comment: not me. thanks for the solution!